# How to delete Uninstaller.exe itself

Tags: installation

The Uninstaller.exe is not getting deleted without reboot. I am using Install Builder bitrock. I found some solution for this issue as :

1. Copy the Uninstall.exe to the windows temp directory
2. Run the Uninstall.exe from the windows temp folder.

Questions:
1. While user clicks Uninstall option  from the start ->Uninstall ->short cut, where I will write the code which supposed to copy the Uninstall.exe to the temp folder.
2. Run the copied the Uninstall.exe from the temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try: [How to force an Uninstall.exe to delete itself](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=HOWTO4342)

Comment: Let me clarify,  the delete functionality should be written in a script/batch. Uninstall operation will run the  batch. Please correct me

Comment: Let me coorect my self again, the mentioned logic that need to be added into my Uninstall.exe, please let me know